# PHP Script problems in posting on the the wall of my facebook fan page and permanent value for $access_token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP SCRIPT issue with passing the uploaded image to facebook->api function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152313/php-script-issue-with-passing-the-uploaded-image-to-facebook-api-function)

I have this code and its working awsomely fine just and just only one problem i am not able to pass my uploaded image to facebook->api (whether its valid or not) and the following always echo 
  echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';
i even remove the check on image type and try to get the image from
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
but $img gets nothing in it and uploads a by default empty image on facebook as my page 
Kindly check my following code and let me know what should is wrong with my code so i'll become able to upload images

```
 <?


require 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = "364900470214655";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true,
 'fileUpload' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
//echo $user;

if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,offline_access,manage_pages'))}");
 exit;
}
else {
$accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
echo "i am connected";
}
  $valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');


//to get the page access token to post as a page
foreach($accounts_list['data'] as $account){
      if($account['id'] == 194458563914948){      // my page id =123456789
        $access_token = $account['access_token'];
        echo "<p>Page Access Token: $access_token</p>";
        }
    }

//posting to the page wall

if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES))
{  
if( !in_array($_FILES['pic']['type'], $valid_files ) )
{
  echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';
 }
 else{
  #Upload photo here
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
$attachment = array('message' => 'this is my message',
                'access_token'  => $access_token,
                'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
                'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
                'link' => 'example.org',
                'description' => 'this is a description',
                'picture' => '@' . $img,
                'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
                                  'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
                );
$status = $facebook->api('/194458563914948/feed', 'POST', $attachment);   // my page id =123456789
var_dump($status);
}
}
?>
<body>
 <!-- Form for uploading the photo -->
 <div class="main">
  <p>Select a photo to upload on Facebook Fan Page</p>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Select the image: <input type="file" name="pic" /></p>
  <p><input class="post_but" type="submit" value="Upload to my album" /></p>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Creating a New Album and Adding a Photo**

This is the scenario where you upload a photo to the ALBUM_ID/photos Graph API endpoint. The user interface for this example allows the user to select a photo and add a caption before submitting the new photo.

Using PHP:

---

```
<?php

       $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
       $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
       $post_login_url = "YOUR_POST-LOGIN_URL";
       $album_name = 'YOUR_ALBUM_NAME';
       $album_description = 'YOUR_ALBUM_DESCRIPTION';

       $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

       //Obtain the access_token with publish_stream permission 
       if(empty($code))
         {
           $dialog_url= "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
           . "client_id=" . $app_id 
           . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($post_login_url)
           . "&scope=publish_stream";
           echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . 
           "'</script>");
       } 
       else {
         $token_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/"
         . "access_token?"
         . "client_id=" .  $app_id 
         . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode( $post_login_url)
         . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
         . "&code=" . $code;
         $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
         $params = null;
         parse_str($response, $params);
         $access_token = $params['access_token'];

         // Create a new album
         $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/albums?"
         . "access_token=". $access_token;

         $postdata = http_build_query(
         array(
          'name' => $album_name,
          'message' => $album_description
            )
          );
         $opts = array('http' =>
         array(
          'method'=> 'POST',
          'header'=>
            'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          'content' => $postdata
          )
         );
         $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
         $result = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url, false, 
           $context));

         // Get the new album ID
         $album_id = $result->id;

         //Show photo upload form and post to the Graph URL
         $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/". $album_id
           . "/photos?access_token=" . $access_token;
         echo '<html><body>';
         echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="'
         .$graph_url. ' "method="POST">';
         echo 'Adding photo to album: ' . $album_name .'<br/><br/>';
         echo 'Please choose a photo: ';
         echo '<input name="source" type="file"><br/><br/>';
         echo 'Say something about this photo: ';
         echo '<input name="message" type="text"
            value=""><br/><br/>';
         echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload" /><br/>';
         echo '</form>';
         echo '</body></html>';
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: well i put the check on user
but there is a problem my following link is not checking if someone is logged in to facebook or not kindly let me know how to provide that

i even put login button on my website to facebook but when someone clicks on it it gives an error

this is my link: http://radiations3.com/facebook/face.php

kindly bear my stupid question i am a rookie..

Comment: http://radiations3.com/facebook/1.php
this link contains the code being provided by the facebook but still when i click on login it gives an error kindly let me know how to check if someone is logged in or not on facebook.

so i can perform my required functionality with the code being given on the following link.

http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-post-on-facebook-page-as-page-not-as-admin-user-using-php-sdk/31/

Comment: what version of php sdk are you using? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Comment: the most recent one.... facebook-php-sdk-v3.1.1-0-g9513f08

Comment: Personally i use javascript sdk to render my login buttons, but use php-sdk for auth wrappers.  Let me post to you my login page so you get an idea of what i am doing.  http://anotherfeed.com/login.php

Comment: $uid = $facebook->getUser();
echo $uid;

it echo 0
i guess i have to add a login button on my domain once i am logged in then i can get user id details etc

and able to post on my fb page

but i am amazed i have a code still that posts in my album without having any login button on my site all it needs my current access token but damn i am not able to post on my fb wall as mentioned above.

Comment: using a page access toke to post to that page does not require login, only a token, posting to a users profile requires that session user be logged in and have given permissions.

Comment: Kindly check my COMPLETE code above:
All i am trying to do is creating such a php script that will allow me to post on the wall of my facebook fanpage from my site... Thanks!!!

Comment: Are you posting as the page or as the session user, to the page?

Comment: i was giving my user access token to the code above and with that it was working fine but when i changed it to get user session on access token then it doesn't and i am posting as my facebook's application on my page.. When ever i upload any image my page gives the notification of 'Deadpinners' upload 1 image (Deadpinners is the name of my application)

Comment: Just for the record all i want to do is to upload status/pics on my facebook page from a php script running on my site..
Any working example would be appreciated thats all.. I just want this functionality

Comment: Its a working link of my script that uploads images to my album of fan page and it'll work until my user session will get expire http://radiations3.com/facebook/face.php

Comment: I edited my answer with a sample of album/photo create from dev blog.  I hope this helps more.

Comment: kindly check my edited code above there was some problems with my app due to which i was facing problems kindly check my edited code aove and let me know how can i resolve the issue that i am currently facing....

Comment: this is my working link that is posting in my page http://radiations3.com/facebook/face.php but image is not appearing :-/

Comment: 90% of my problem is being resolved kindly check my above code the most recent verion and let me know what exactly am i doing wrong????

Comment: i tested the photo upload and it uploaded with success, i am not sure though where it uploaded to .  OK i found it, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=194458563914948_415430361817766  Everything seems to be working fine, i am assuming what is left is handling expired tokens correct?

Comment: Issue is being resolved now there was a problem with this line of code 'source' => '@' . $img, and when i changed it to 'source' => '@' . realpath($folder), then the code worked like a charm....