# PHP SCRIPT issue with passing the uploaded image to facebook->api function

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code and its working awsomely fine if i provide a direct link of an image.

---

Just and just only one problem i am not able to pass my uploaded image to facebook->api (whether its valid or not) and the following always echo

---

echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';

---

i even remove the check on image type and try to get the image from
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
but $img gets nothing in it and uploads a by default empty image on facebook as my page 
Kindly check my following code and let me know what is wrong with my code and what should i do instead to upload images

Online link of the following CODE: http://radiations3.com/facebook/1.php

```
 <?


require 'src/facebook.php';

$app_id = "364900470214655";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxxx";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true,
 'fileUpload' => true,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();
//echo $user;

if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
 header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,offline_access,manage_pages'))}");
 exit;
}
else {
$accounts_list = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');
echo "i am connected";
}
  $valid_files = array('image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif');


//to get the page access token to post as a page
foreach($accounts_list['data'] as $account){
      if($account['id'] == 194458563914948){      // my page id =123456789
        $access_token = $account['access_token'];
        echo "<p>Page Access Token: $access_token</p>";
        }
    }

//posting to the page wall

if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES))
{  
if( !in_array($_FILES['pic']['type'], $valid_files ) )
{
  echo 'Only jpg, png and gif image types are supported!';
 }
 else{
  #Upload photo here
  $img = realpath($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"]);
$attachment = array('message' => 'this is my message',
                'access_token'  => $access_token,
                'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
                'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
                'link' => 'example.org',
                'description' => 'this is a description',
                'picture' => '@' . $img,
                'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
                                  'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
                );
$status = $facebook->api('/194458563914948/feed', 'POST', $attachment);   // my page id =123456789
var_dump($status);
}
}
?>
<body>
 <!-- Form for uploading the photo -->
 <div class="main">
  <p>Select a photo to upload on Facebook Fan Page</p>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p>Select the image: <input type="file" name="pic" /></p>
  <p><input class="post_but" type="submit" value="Upload to my album" /></p>
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Mark Duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10141801/php-script-problems-in-posting-on-the-the-wall-of-my-facebook-fan-page-and-perma/10143305#10143305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon uploading, i received the following callback

> i am connectedarray(1) { ["id"]=> string(31)
>   "194458563914948_415487041812098" }

graph api explorer suggests the upload was successful

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=194458563914948_415487041812098

Comment: ok kindly let me know one thing the server of my website was down so i thoght to check up my FB UPload script on my other domains but when i put files over there then i am not able to login to my facebook from that site using my same application id and secret . Is it necessary for an application to give right to that domain only which is being mentioned in its website URL section??? 'I am confused totally confused'

Comment: You can not use multible domains for an application.  The domain you set your application too in the settings is the only domain that will work unless you change the settings to a new domain.

Comment: thanx alot for helping me out !!! So far my issue is being solved if i'll get into trouble i'll let you know